# Convert recursive void to recursive string function in C#

Tags: c#, string, recursion, void

I want to get the results of this code as a string **so I can calculate it's length and get the longest string to write it**

```
static void function2(int i, int j, string str)
{
    if (str.Split(' ')[i] == str.Split(' ')[j])
    {
        Console.Write(" {0}", str.Split(' ')[i]);
        i++; j++;
        function2(i, j, str);
    }
}
```

this is the recursive code that I want to get the result of it(`Console.Write(" {0}", str.Split(' ')[i]);`) and here is part of the public buddy :

```
for (m = 0; m < c2 - 1; m++)
{
    i = 0; j = 1;
    while (j < c2)
    {
        function2(i, j, str);
        j++;
    }
    str = str.Remove(0, str.Split(' ')[i].Length + 1);
    c2--;
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

I tried to change the title of the recursive code from `static void function2` to `static string function2` and add return, but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the purpose of the function? `function2` doesn't really tell me what the function is for.

Comment: do you assign the returned value to a variable? Please share the code that includes your return statements

Comment: the purpose of function2 is to get a string and find if there's any word in that string same as the first word of it then print it.
Like in the string "animals are good and animals are beautiful" it will print animals then in the buddy I remove the word animals (`str = str.Remove(0, str.Split(' ')[i].Length + 1);` so the string will start with the word "are" and it will print "are".. the same thing goes on.

Comment: Does your solution *have* to be recursive?  I think your entire two blocks of code could probably be replaced by 3-4 lines if you made it more clear exactly what you needed (inputs and expected outputs)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep the calling code as is and just make function2 return the matched string you can do something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    int m; 
    int i; 
    int j; 
    int c2;
    string str = "animals are good and animals are beautiful";

    c2 = str.Split(' ').Length;

    for (m = 0; m < c2 - 1; m++)
    {
       i = 0; j = 1;
       while (j < c2)
       {
           String res = function2(i, j, str);
           // Do what you need to do with the string
           Console.WriteLine(res);
           j++;
       }
       str = str.Remove(0, str.Split(' ')[i].Length + 1);
       c2--;
       Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}

static String function2(int i, int j, string str)
{
    String res = "";

    if (str.Split(' ')[i] == str.Split(' ')[j])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" {0}", str.Split(' ')[i]);

        // Keep the matching string in a variable
        res = str.Split(' ')[i];

        i++; j++;

        // And add it to the return
        return res + " " + function2(i, j, str);
    }

    // Where it used to be void return an empty string
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for stats from the words your string, and don't really *need* recursion, then here is an example of how to get some of the stats you want.  Note you'll need `using System.Linq;`.

```
var words = str.Split(' ');
var firstWord = words[0];
var hasAnyMore = words.Any(word => word == firstWord);
var longestWord = words.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Length > y.Length ? x : y);
var wordCount = words.Length;
```

Comment: `hasAnyMore` will always return `true`, since `words` contain at least one `firstWord`, that is the first item of `words`.

Comment: @ken fair enough. Add a Skip 1 to it.